# set maximum limits in mysql sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, max, limit

I have 2 tables. Concerts / Tickets

I want to set Concert 1 to have maximum of 100 tickets and Concert 2 to have maximum of 200 tickets. so like have a concert_id be linked with a maximum number of ticket_id.

How can I do this in mysql? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write triggers:

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists limitInsertsTrigger //
create trigger limitInsertsTrigger before insert on tickets
for each row
begin
    declare msg varchar(128);
    if  (select count(*) from tickets where concert_id = new.concert_id)> 
        (select max_tickets_number from concert where id=new.concert_id)
    then
        set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Trying to insert too many tickets');
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    end if;
end //
```

Remember to have a max_tickets_number column in the concert table.

Comment: so this trigger is like a command that you would type in the mysql shell commands? I am using using  mysql workbench atm.

sorry if my questions are noobish. i am new cs student.

Comment: The trigger is like a table definition. You can copy and paste in mysql workbench and run it.

Comment: is it also possible to do something in reverse? like a column that starts out with a maximum number, and automatically ticks down as rows are added?

Comment: You can do that but it's not useful data. You can set a column of concert with the maximum number, then check this value all the time in the trigger. I will update it

Comment: thank you. i will investigate more and try and implement this in workbench.

Comment: what does the "signal sqlstate" mean / do?

Comment: It's returning the error when the number of tickets exceeds.